# webPack dev server proxy rewrite URLs in response

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm attempting to migrate from BrowserSync to Webpack Dev Server for hot-reloading my front-end assets in my local development server for a PHP application.

I've got everything working with a proxy, such that my application which is already running at https://localhost, is being proxied to https://localhost:3000, and my assets are successfully being served from `localhost:3000/dist/foo.js` and `localhost:3000/dist/bar.css`.

The problem is that the markup still says

```
<script src="https://localhost/dist/foo.js"></script>
<link href="https://localhost/dist/bar.css">
```

These assets 404 because the `/dist` directory only exists at port 3000.

BrowserSync would update these paths in my html to point to the correct port, but I can't figure out how to do the same with WebPack dev server.

I'm using Webpack 4.29.3 and webpack dev server 3.1.14. Config below:

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    "**": {
      target: 'https://localhost',
      secure: false
    }
  },
  hot: true,
  port: 3000,
  https: true
},
```

Comment: you need establish a proxy for assets on `https://localhost:3000` on your PHP server side.

Comment: @lx1412 That's something I'd rather not do. I'd like to be able to run my app both with and without the webpack proxy. When I'm doing backend work I don't use webpack dev server. I just want to spin it up when doing css and just work.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite body in the proxy - that's what you shouldn't probably do.

### Composition of URLs

The question is - how are you generating those urls in the php files?
Are they procedurally generated by some function or hardcoded?

You could change it to

```html
<script src="/dist/foo.js"></script>
<link href="/dist/bar.css">
```

This will work for any host you're visiting the site from as this is relative path.

- on `localhost:3000`, it will point to `localhost:3000/dist/foo.js`
- on `https://localhost` it will point to `https://localhost/dist/foo.js`

### Change origin

Second thing that comes to my mind is to use option `changeOrigin` to `true/false` and watch how the URLs modify according to this.
If your server is creating the urls from request, it might be that the proxied request is not using the origin of the proxied server.